# Wrap list items in two columns with wrapAll() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to wrap multiple li groups in two div's, since items get rendered inside one `<ul>` via CMS. So the situation is like this:

```
<ul>
    <li class="list-1">
        <span>1</span>
        <span>2</span>
        <span>3</span>
    </li>
        <li class="list-2">
        <span>1</span>
        <span>2</span>
        <span>3</span>
    </li>
        <li class="list-3">
        <span>1</span>
        <span>2</span>
        <span>3</span>
    </li>
        <li class="list-4">
        <span>1</span>
        <span>2</span>
        <span>3</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

But I would like to use jquery wrapAll method or similar to group list-1 and list-2 into one div, and list-3 with list-4 into second one, to get this result:

```html
<ul>
    <div class="group-1">
        <li class="list-1">
            <span>1</span>
            <span>2</span>
            <span>3</span>
        </li>
            <li class="list-2">
            <span>1</span>
            <span>2</span>
            <span>3</span>
        </li>
    </div>
    <div class="group-2">
        <li class="list-3">
            <span>1</span>
            <span>2</span>
            <span>3</span>
        </li>
            <li class="list-4">
            <span>1</span>
            <span>2</span>
            <span>3</span>
        </li>
    </div>
    </ul>
```

Is there a way I could achieve this with something like:

```
$( "li:nth-child(1), li:nth-child(2)" ).wrapAll( "<div class='group-1'></div>" );
```

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Is this ok using css?

Comment: Only if there is an option to wrap via nth:child or similar… I need to wrap first two li's into one div and other two into the second via JS, in order to separate them into flex containers

Comment: Note `ul` can **only** have `li` as children so your HTML would be invalid. - You would need something like this to be correct - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/WNNzmjK

Comment: yes...is there any other way I could achieve the separation..?

Comment: You have not defined *"the separation"*. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I would like to be able to set display: flex to first two li's, so that it breaks on the third li

Comment: `$( "li:nth-child(1), li:nth-child(2)" ).wrapAll( "<li><ul></ul></li>" );` will do the wrapping but you would need to loop it over your chose parent.

Comment: Are you looking for [`columns`](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/1kc7m35y/)?

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu very close but not quite - some items from the third column went into the second one and similar - any way to control this?

Comment: Yep, with `break-inside: avoid`. Updated it.

Answer (score 0):

You can separate `li` in groups by using this function.

You have to change only `groupSep` variable and your list will be grouped as per variable value.

In your case, I have set `groupSep = 2`.

**Here is Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var groupCounter = 1;
  var groupSep = 2;
  var liHtml = '';
 $('ul > li').each(function(index, el){
    if(((index+1) % groupSep) === 1){
      $('ul').append('<div class="group-'+groupCounter+'"></div>');
      for(i=0; i<groupSep; i++){
        $('ul > li').eq(0).appendTo('ul .group-'+groupCounter);
      }
      groupCounter++;
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li class="list-1">
        <span>1</span>
        <span>2</span>
        <span>3</span>
    </li>
        <li class="list-2">
        <span>1</span>
        <span>2</span>
        <span>3</span>
    </li>
        <li class="list-3">
        <span>1</span>
        <span>2</span>
        <span>3</span>
    </li>
        <li class="list-4">
        <span>1</span>
        <span>2</span>
        <span>3</span>
    </li>
      <li class="list-5">
        <span>1</span>
        <span>2</span>
        <span>3</span>
    </li>
      <li class="list-6">
        <span>1</span>
        <span>2</span>
        <span>3</span>
    </li>
      <li class="list-7">
        <span>1</span>
        <span>2</span>
        <span>3</span>
    </li>
      <li class="list-8">
        <span>1</span>
        <span>2</span>
        <span>3</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```